# Remove a link from a list of links

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I remove a link from a list of links below if a link is clicked.  The HTML for the links is a follows

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/page1.html" class="standard_link">link 1</a><br />
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/page2.html" class="standard_link">link 2</a><br />
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/page3.html" class="standard_link">link 3</a><br />
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/page4.html" class="standard_link">link 4</a><br />
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/page5.html" class="standard_link">link 5</a><br />
```

EDIT: Just realised that I need to `<br />` to be removed too, so the remaining links move up.  Looks weird with a gap where the link was removed.

EDIT: Here is the current script:

```
$(".standard_link").live('click', function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();

    my_function($(this))
});

function my_function(link)
{
    // do some stuff first  

    // remove the clicked link plus the <br />
    link.add(link.nextSibling).remove();

    // do some other stuff
}
```

Comment: Which link do you want to remove? How do you know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('a.standard_link').click(function(){ // when any link with the class "standard_link" is clicked
    $(this).remove(); // remove it
});
```

NB that if you want to avoid the default event occuring, you'll need [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault):

```
$('a.standard_link').click(function(e){ // when any link with the class "standard_link" is clicked
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).remove(); // remove it
});
```

---

Edit: to remove the `<br/>` as well, use [`add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
$(this).add(this.nextSibling).remove();
```

Note that this will break if there is *anything* (including white space) between the link and the line break.

Comment: How would I remove the <br /> too?  I want the rest of the links to move up if a link is deleted.

Comment: So I do the this.remove and then a this.add directly below the this.remove?

Comment: No, put that line in instead of the `// remove it` line above.

Comment: It removes the link but it will not bring the rest up.  I will update my original post to include all the current script.

Comment: @oshirowanen You are calling `nextSibling` on a jQuery selection, whereas it is a DOM element property. Try using `link.add(link.next('br')).remove();`, which is the jQuery equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".standard_link").click(function(){
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: How would I remove the <br /> too? I want the rest of the links to move up if a link is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vague. In truth there are [*many* possibilities](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). It all depends on your exact requirement.

```
// link href contains 'page5'
$("a[href*=page5]").remove();

// links ending with page5.html
$("a[href$=page5\\.html]").remove();

// remove all links with some class
$(".standard_link").remove();
```

If you want to target based on the text or html content of the link, you can do:

```
$("a.standard_link").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == "link 2";
}).remove();
```

Comment: How would I remove the <br /> too? I want the rest of the links to move up if a link is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need JavaScript at all.  In CSS, you can cause visited links to not display, for example:

```
a:visited { display: none; }
```

Comment: But this hidden link will still exist as far as any scripts on the page are concerned; it is only the browser that it will be invisible to.  By removing the link in JavaScript, it will no longer interfere, for example, if a script is iterating through all the links on a page.